# Delete the row if it contains more than specific number of non numeric values

Tags: bash, awk, sed, preprocessor, gawk

I have a large (2GB) comma separated textfile containing some data from Sensors. Sometimes the sensors are off and there is no data. I want to delete the rows if there are more than specified number of `No Data` or `Off` or `any non-numeric` values in each row; excluding the header. I am only interested in counting from 3rd column onwards. For example: my data looks like:

```
Tag, Description,2015/01/01,2015/01/01 00:01:00,2015/01/01 00:02:00, 2015/01/01 00:02:00
1827XYZR/KB.SAT,Data from Process Value,2.1,Off,2.7
1871XYZR/KB.RAT,Data from process value,Off,No Data, No Data
1962XYMK/KB.GAT,Data from Process Value,No Data,5,3
1867XYST/KB.FAT,Data from process value,1.05,5.87,7.80
1871XKZR/KB.VAT,Data from process value,No Data,Off,2
```

Here first row is the header and I want to keep it as is. But I want delete those rows that have 2 or more than 2 `No Data` or `Off` or any `non numeric` fields in any columns/fields from 3rd column onwards. In other words, rows having 4 or text fields out of five. In the example, above 3rd and 6th row have 2 or more than 2 `No Data` or `Off` fields and I want to delete them. Therefore, my preferred output would be

```
Tag, Description,2015/01/01,2015/01/01 00:01:00,2015/01/01 00:02:00, 2015/01/01 00:02:00
1827XYZR/KB.SAT,Data from Process Value,2.1,Off,2.7
1962XYMK/KB.GAT,Data from Process Value,No Data,5,3
1867XYST/KB.FAT,Data from process value,1.05,5.87,7.80
```

I can do this for specific case with a loop as:

```
awk -F, '{ non_numeric=0;
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i ~ // ) non_numeric++
  }
  if(non_numeric<2) print $0
}' testfile.txt
```

Here, I am considering only `No Data` and `Off`. How can I count all non-numeric strings. If I change the if statement to

```
if($i ~ /[^0-9]/ ) non_numeric++
```

it does not work and gives no output. Also since I am using loop, I reckon it is going to be slow. Can we speed this up, somehow. Any Commandline solution is Ok.

Comment: Use a `for()` loop to count the number of numeric fields. Whenthe loop is done, print the line if it's at least 4.

Comment: Basically, I just restated your requirement. It should be straightforward to turn it into `awk` code. Please show what you tried so we can help you fix it. We're not going to do your work for you.

Comment: The third line in the sample data contains the following: `No Data. No Data`. Is this a typo? was the `.` supposed to be a `,`?

Comment: @Barmar and redneb I have added own work and fixed the typo in the data. Sorry for not being discrete.

Comment: `[^0-9]` will reject numbers that contain a decimal point.

Comment: No matter how you do it, processing a 2GB file will be slow.

Comment: could you clarify.. 1) `3rd and 5th row` should be `3rd and 6th row`? 2) `more than 2 No Data or Off` it says more than 2, so how last row is getting cut? 3) `more than specified number of No Data in each row` opening para, missing `Off` here? 4) Are you interested in checking values only from 3rd column onwards, excluding the header?

Comment: @spasic : 1. Yes 2. More than two `No Data` or `Off` or any `non-numeric` characters. Numeric should consider decimal places, i.e., 4.25 is a number. 3. Yes. 4. Yes. I have updated the question too.

Comment: thanks for clarification, however am still not clear how last row gets cut off.. I see only two non-numeric fields `No Data,Off` the other being valid data of `2`

Comment: It should have been two or more than two. I have also corrected that in question, sorry for the mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with `grep`:

```
grep -vP '((?<=,|^)(No Data|Off)(?=,|$).*){2,}' input

Tag, Description,2015/01/01,2015/01/01 00:01:00,2015/01/01 00:02:00, 2015/01/01 00:02:00
1827XYZR/KB.SAT,Data from Process Value,2.1,Off,2.7
1962XYMK/KB.GAT,Data from Process Value,No Data,5,3
1867XYST/KB.FAT,Data from process value,1.05,5.87,7.80
```

Explanation: `(No Data|Off)` matches with either `No Data` or `Off`. We surround it by `(?<=,|^)` and `(?=,|$)`; these are a zero-width lookbehind and lookahead that match with a `,` or the beginning (or the end) of the string. This ensures that we are matching with a whole field only. Since we want to match with a field multiple times, we put everything inside a quantified `(...){2,}` and we also add a `.*` to account for the stuff between the fields.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F, '
    {   nonnum = 0;
        for (i = 3; i <= NF; i++) { 
            if ($i ~ /[^.0-9]/) {
                nonnum++;
                if(nonnum >= 2) { next; }
            }
        }
    } 1' infile > outfile
```

The `1` at the end prints the line if the loop never executed `next` to skip remaining patterns for the current line.

Comment: Thanks! I think it should be ` i <= NF` it would fail for case when last three columns are numeric, non-numeric, non-numeric. I will wait for sometime if I get a faster solution, otherwise I will accept this answer.

Comment: I think, [the `break;` statement after `next;` is redundant](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Next-Statement.html), though harmless...

Answer (score 1):

WIth static strings:

```
$ awk '(a=$0) && gsub(/No Data|Off/,"",a)<2' file
```

Ie. copy the current record `$0` to a temp variable `a`, count the number of occurrances of `Off` and `No Data` using `gsub` and `print` if count is less than 2. Output:

```
Tag, Description,2015/01/01,2015/01/01 00:01:00,2015/01/01 00:02:00, 2015/01/01 00:02:00
1827XYZR/KB.SAT,Data from Process Value,2.1,Off,2.7
1962XYMK/KB.GAT,Data from Process Value,No Data,5,3
1867XYST/KB.FAT,Data from process value,1.05,5.87,7.80
```

If you want to match all non-numeric strings, use:

```
awk 'NR==1 || (a=$0) && gsub(/,[^\.,0-9]+/,"",a)<3' file
```

It outputs first record (`NR==1`) and records with less than three non-numeric values (third one is the `,Data from process value`).

Comment: Thanks but is there a way, a regex to consider other strings as well, I want to count everything that is non-numeric  using /[^0-9.]/ in gsub does't work

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk you can use this goody:

```
awk 'NF<2' FPAT='No Data' file
```

`FPAT` specifies a pattern that describes what is a field in a line of text. It is a GNU extension. Setting it to the static string `No Data` allows us to simply check the field count with `NF<2`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ perl -F, -ane 'print if $. == 1 || (grep {!/\d/} @F[2..$#F]) < 2' ip.txt 
Tag, Description,2015/01/01,2015/01/01 00:01:00,2015/01/01 00:02:00, 2015/01/01 00:02:00
1827XYZR/KB.SAT,Data from Process Value,2.1,Off,2.7
1962XYMK/KB.GAT,Data from Process Value,No Data,5,3
1867XYST/KB.FAT,Data from process value,1.05,5.87,7.80
```

- `-F,` split input line on `,`
- `$. == 1` if line number is `1`, i.e print the header
- `(grep {!/\d/} @F[2..$#F]) < 2` print if number of non-numeric fields in columns 3 to end is less than two. The condition simply checks if digit is not present

The columns to check and number of times to check can easily be changed depending on requirement. For ex: `@F[3..$#F]` checks 4th column onwards, `< 3` checks number of non-numeric fields less than three

Answer (score 0):

lazy way: print iff fields 3-5 contain at least one number character:

```
awk -F, '$3$4$5 ~ "[0-9]"' data.csv
```

lazier way (works for your sample data): print iff row contains a comma followed by a number character:

```
grep ',[0-9]' data.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/(.*No Data|.*Off){2}/d' file
```

Use alternation to delete lines with 2 or more of the designated strings.

Comment: Is there a way, a regex to consider other strings as well, I want to count everything that is non-numeric