# Delete the column/field if it contains more than specific number of non-numeric values

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, gawk

Similar to my earlier question [Delete the row if it contains more than specific number of non numeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39501771/delete-the-row-if-it-contains-more-than-specific-number-of-non-numeric-values/39524671#39524671), I have a data that has non-numeric fields:
I want to delete those columns (fields) that has more than specific number of non-numeric characters (`Off` and `No Data`) in this example. I want to count from 3rd field onwards, i.e, forget the first two rows.

```
Tag, Description,2015/01/01,2015/01/01 00:01:00,2015/01/01 00:02:00
1827XYZR/KB.SAT,Data from Process Value, 2.10000, No Data, 2.7
1871XYZR/KB.RAT,Data from process value, Off    , 2.87583, No Data
1962XYMK/KB.GAT,Data from Process Value, No Data, 5      , 3
1867XYST/KB.FAT,Data from process value, 1.05000, 5.87   , 7.80
1871XKZR/KB.VAT,Data from process value, No Data, Off    , 2
```

In the data above (there are no spaces, I have kept it only to show the formatting), I want to delete all those columns that has more than two (3 or more) occurrence of non-numeric characters. Here, Column 3 has two `No Data` and one `Off`, so I want to delete the 3rd Column here. I tried this in a loop without success

```
awk -F ',' '{
for(n=3; n<=NF; n++)
    {   
        a = $n
        if(n!=NF)
        {
            fmt="%s,";
        }               
        else
        {
            fmt="%s\n";
        }
        if(gsub(/No Data|Off/,"",a)<2)
        {   
            printf(fmt,$n);
        }       
    }
 }' testfile.txt
```

I also tried

```
awk -F, '{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++)if(gsub(/No Data|Off/,"",$i)<3)f=f?f FS $i:$i;print f;f=""}' testfile.txt
```

but this only deletes the the words `No Data` and `Off` but keeps the fields (columns) intact. My desired output is:

```
Tag, Description,2015/01/01 00:01:00,2015/01/01 00:02:00
1827XYZR/KB.SAT,Data from Process Value, Off     ,2.7
1871XYZR/KB.RAT,Data from process value, 2.87583 ,No Data
1962XYMK/KB.GAT,Data from Process Value, 5       ,3
1867XYST/KB.FAT,Data from process value, 5.87    ,7.80
1871XKZR/KB.VAT,Data from process value, Off     ,2
```

Comment: You have been asking this before

Comment: @hek2mgl It's not the same; in the referred duplicate he would like to remove rows, in this one columns. It is completely different problem.

Comment: @JamesBrown Missed that. Question re-opened

Comment: Yea, it seem familiar to me too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk -F, '{
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
      cell[NR,i]=$i
      if (i>2 && $i+0 != $i)
         nn[i]++
   }
   nf=NF
   nr=NR
} 
END {
   for (r=1; r<=nr; r++) {
      for (c=1; c<=nf; c++)
         if (nn[c]<4)
            printf "%s%s", (c>1?FS:""), cell[r,c]
      print ""
   }
}' file

Tag,Description,2015/01/01 00:01:00,2015/01/01 00:02:00
1827XYZR/KB.SAT,Data from Process Value,No Data,2.7
1871XYZR/KB.RAT,Data from process value,2.87583,No Data
1962XYMK/KB.GAT,Data from Process Value,5      ,3
1867XYST/KB.FAT,Data from process value,5.87   ,7.80
1871XKZR/KB.VAT,Data from process value,Off    ,2
```